# Domain of the closure of an unbounded operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $D$ and $F$ be two unbounded on a Hilbert space $H$ whose dense domains of definition coincide. Moreover, assume that each is a symmetric operator. As is well-known, each operator is closable, i.e. extendable to a closed operator.

Will their extended domains coincide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why. On $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ consider the operators 
$$
D = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\quad \text{ and } \quad F = \frac{d^4}{dx^4}
$$
each with the domain $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ (infinitely smooth functions with compact support). They are both symmetric. Both are closable, but the closure of $D$ is defined on the Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ while the closure of $F$ is defined on a smaller Sobolev space $H^4(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: What extra requirements on the two operators would imply that their domains coincide?

Comment: For example, $F=AD$ where $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Where A has the same domain as F and D I guess?

Comment: Also, is it easy to see why this is the case?

Comment: By an invertible operator I mean a bounded invertible operator, with the domain being the entire Hilbert space $H$. The map $(x,y)\mapsto (x, Ay)$ is a homeomorphism of $H\times H$ onto itself. So the closure of image of any set under this map is the image of closure. This is why composition with $A$ does not change the domain of the closure.